# Is it good practice to create large number of js file or combine in to one

Tags: javascript

We have large number of forms. What we have done so far is that each form pages have their corresponding js file with logic in it.

The logic is to capture form data and call the dataservice.js which performs ajax call to server.

Wondering if creating a JS file for each form is good practice or should create ONE big file containing all logics? Note the code within each JS files are not re-usable.

Comment: Are all your forms on 1 page? If not then what's the point of combining all of them into 1 file?

Answer (score 1):

For development you should keep them separate to make it easier to find the right one and keep everything a little cleaner.

However, for production you want to put them altogether in one file.
The main reason is performance: It's just faster to load one file than it is to load multiple files mostly because you just need one http request.

You can automate that, for example with grunt or gulp or whatever automation tool you are using anyway already.

Comment: This is assuming that there are multiple forms on one page. Of course you can still bundle js for a particular page but probably not all the forms if you only have 1 form per page

Comment: That's a good point! If it's not a single Application that makes sense.

However if you expect a user to visit all sites anyway it can make sense cause the browser will just load the JS file on the first page and use on the other pages the cache so you still save one request on every subpage...